# How to migrate to a non-SQL Server virtual machine

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-sql-server

I provisioned an Azure VM with SQL Server pre-installed on Azure, but the decision has been made to re-install SQL Server with a different license. According to [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-server-iaas-faq) that means that I need to "deploy a new virtual machine and migrate the data and applications to the new virtual machine". Can I back up the OS VHD and migrate that to a new Azure VM without losing the applications and other prep work that's already been done and as a result drop the extra costs associated with using a SQL Server VM? How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, unfortunately not.

You need to backup your data, move it off the VM (say to blob storage using AzCopy), build a new VM choosing the right license/sku from the store, then restore your backup and redeploy your apps.

See a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474896/how-to-change-sql-server-license-in-azure-vm) here